# Repeatingly increase an object size with certain amount of px

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

Fairly new to AI, certainly to scripting. I'm trying to recreate this poster:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I want to automate the creation of the large amount of circles. I want to record an action that I can apply to a shape (in this case a circle) to do the following:

- copy the shape
- paste it on the exact same place
- move the object 2 px up and 2 px left
- increase the size of the object with 4 px.

I found the moving part, but increasing the size with a certain amount of px seems impossible. The action records the scaling as a percentage, resulting in increasingly bigger distances between the circles.

Is there a way to record an action that that makes every copy move by the same amount of pixels? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option One

- Grab the **Polar Grid Tool**

[image: Polar Grid]

- Click and drag on the artboard to draw an ellipse. Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to create a perfect circle.
- **While still dragging with the mouse** use the **up and down arrows** to add/subtract inner circles, use the **left and right arrows** to add/remove the inner crossing spines.

[image: polar grid]

- When you're happy, simply let go of the mouse.

---

### Option Two

- Draw the inner small circle.
- Draw the outer large circle.
- Select both
- Choose `Object > Blend > Make`
- Choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and set the drop down menu to Specified steps and increase the steps until you are happy.

[image: steps]

- Click OK.

If you now want the circles as separate objects, choose `Object > Expand` and tick *only* the `Object` box and click OK.

[image: expand]

---

There ya go. A whole slew of perfectly aligned and spaced circles in moments.

**Regarding the specific question about actions and movements:**

Yes you can record an action which moves an object a specific amount. However, you should realize that the action will use the object bounds as the basis for the movement. And, with ever increasing object sizes the pixel movement would need to increase each step. That can't be done in actions (unless you increase by a relative value like a percentage) and would require scripting. 2 pixels may work for the first duplication, but the second would require 4px, then 6px, then 8px etc.

If I *had* to use an action to create these circles (which I normally would't - see above), I would simply use the action to duplicate and resize, the `Select All`, then `Center horizontally` and `Center Vertically` - repeat. I wouldn't try moving each and every circle a couple pixels and then resizing it. Centering the circles after they've been duplicated and resized will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Select object > right click - Scale (choose uniform), uncheck Scale strokes & fx and press copy. Cmd + D forever :)